# Project Euclidian tensor of fourth order onto subspace of Hooke's tensors

Tags: group-theory, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

For a given Euclidian tensor of fourth order in three dimensions $\mathbf{A}$, how does one compute the Hooke's part $\mathbf{H}$ of $\mathbf{A}$?

With the space of Hooke's tensors $\mathcal{H}$, containing tensors with inner symmetry, i.e. both minor symmetries and the major symmetry, i.e. the property $H_{ijkl} = H_{jikl} = H_{ijlk} = H_{klij}$.

[Rychlewski 2000]
introduces the subgroup of permutations
$\Sigma_{\mathcal{H}} = \{(1234), (2134), (1243), (3412), (2143), (4321), (1423), (1324)\}$
and a projector 
$\mathcal{s}_{\mathcal{H}} = \frac{1}{8}(\sum_{i=1}^8 \sigma_{i})$ with $\sigma_i \in \Sigma_{\mathcal{H}}$
projecting onto the 21-dimensional space of Hooke's tensors.
This is exactly what is needed.
However, implementing the projector using
$\sigma \times 
(\mathbf{a}_1 \otimes \mathbf{a}_2 \otimes \mathbf{a}_3 \otimes \mathbf{a}_4) = 
\mathbf{a}_{\sigma^{-1}(1)} \otimes
\mathbf{a}_{\sigma^{-1}(2)} \otimes
\mathbf{a}_{\sigma^{-1}(3)} \otimes
\mathbf{a}_{\sigma^{-1}(4)}$
with permutation being for example $\sigma = (2413)$, meaning $\sigma(1) = 2, \sigma(2) = 4, \sigma(3) = 1, \sigma(4) = 3,$ does not yield the expected result.

What have I done wrong or misunderstood?

Implementation:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(3, 3, 3, 3)

permutations_inv = [
    (0, 1, 2, 3),
    (1, 0, 2, 3),
    (0, 1, 3, 2),
    (2, 3, 0, 1),
    (1, 0, 3, 2),
    (3, 2, 1, 0),
    (0, 3, 1, 2),
    (0, 2, 1, 3),
    ]

# Invert permutation according definition
permutations = []
for p in permutations_inv:
    permutations.append([
            p.index(0),
            p.index(1),
            p.index(2),
            p.index(3),
            ])

H = 1.0/len(permutations) * sum(
                            A.transpose(perm)
                            for perm in permutations
                            )


def has_sym_inner(A):
    sym = True
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                for l in range(3):
                    if not all(
                                [
                                    A[i, j, k, l] == A[j, i, k, l],
                                    A[i, j, k, l] == A[i, j, l, k],
                                    A[i, j, k, l] == A[k, l, i, j]
                                ]
                                ):
                        sym = False

    return sym

print('has_sym_inner =', has_sym_inner(H))
```

Verifying visually using
[mechkit](https://mechkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/notation.html)

```
import mechkit
con = mechkit.notation.Converter()
print('A=\n', con.to_mandel9(A))
print('H=\n', con.to_mandel9(H))
```

[image]

[Rychlewski 2000]: Rychlewski, J. (2000). A qualitative approach to Hooke's tensors. Part I. Archives of Mechanics, 52(4-5), 737-759

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about debugging code. [so] or [scicomp.se] might be better suited, if adapted for those audiences.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I added the code to illustrate my state of knowledge on the topic.
I can validate whether the result is a Hooke's tensor. However, I am totally new to group-theory and permutations, so changes are high, that I have missed an essential point which could become obvious by sharing the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the professor Rychlewski's paper, i.e. the last two permutations are incorrect (wrong).
The correct Hooke's tensor symmetrization permutations are as follows:
(1234),(1243),(2134),(2143),(3412),(4312),(3421),(4321)

Comment: Thank you! I implemented the permutations proposed by you and can confirm that applying these permutations to a random tensor of fourth order yields a tensor which possesses inner symmetry. In addition, even without knowledge on group-theory, the permutations proposed by you seem intuitively reasonable to me. Are these permutations unique?